# Access full url from grandfather component

Tags: angular

I'm trying to read the full url from a grandfather component using:

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit{
    myURL:any;
    constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute){
    }
    ngOnInit(){
        this.myURL = this.route.snapshot.url;
    }
}
```

But I only get the '' as *myURL*.

I have my path configuration correctly implemented and I can navigate to:
http://localhost:4200/index/notes/note1/Support
in which I can view my AppComponent, IndexComponent, NotesComponent, NoteComponent and ProductComponent. If I cast from the grandchild:

```
this.myURL = this.route.snapshot.url;
```

It returns the full Url, but i need to have access to it in the AppComponent.

Using at AppComponent:

```
this.myURL = this.route.children[0];
```

returns undefined

Comment: `onInit()` is it a typo in your code or you just missed while framing the question?

Comment: Yes, thanks. I typed that part instead of copying it.